# Error while installing openstack via openstack-packstack

Tags: openstack

I have followed https://www.rdoproject.org/Quickstart to install openstack in a CentOS virtualbox.

I got the following error output while running `sudo yum install -y openstack-packstack`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.excellmedia.net
* extras: centos.excellmedia.net
* updates: centos.excellmedia.net
http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-kilo/%25FDIST%25%25RELEASEVER%25/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror. 
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository:   openstack-kilo. Please verify its path and try again
```

This url is not accessible from other machines as well. CentOS VM have the internet connection as well. Appreciate your help in resolving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with actually trying the URL:

1. If you navigate manually, you are switched to HTTPS:

   https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-kilo/
2. Since you are on CentOs 7, simply specify:

   https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-kilo/el7/repodata/repomd.xml

... in `/etc/yum.repos.d` where there's a .repo file with the wrong URL in it.

Comment: where can I  specify this url?.

Comment: @apremalal - in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory there's a .repo file with incorrect url. Fix it and you're done.